# How to access database from derby in the same directory as jar?

Tags: java, database, derby

I have developed a movie organizer program in Java with derby database. It works fine on my computer, however I couldn't figure out how to make it "portable" (only for my own use).

My problem is, that if I use the

```
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost/Movie";
```

code for the connection to the derby database, it is only working on my computer as it is the path specified directly to my Netbeans database location. I would like to put the Movie folder near the .jar file of the application and make it portable so I can use the same database everywhere.

Any help would be appreciated on how could I achieve this.

Comment: May I recommend you work through the tutorial: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html The differences between embedded mode configurations and client-server mode configurations and all the various choices available to you via the JDBC Connection URL will make a lot more sense once you're more comfortable with the basics of how to use Derby.

Comment: I have seen it before, but I haven't found anything relevant in it about my problem.

Comment: OK, but did it help you understand that part of your problem is that the JDBC Connection URL in your question is for a client-server configuration, but if you are asking about where to locate your database on the machine where your app is stored, you need to use an embedded configuration instead, with a different JDBC Connection URL and a different CLASSPATH? I think I'm trying to persuade you that you will be more successful if you understand the Derby **architecture** first, and then try to configure the details of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the database from the filesystem for example like this:

```
jdbc:derby:./myDatabaseName
```

Comment: I have tried it by putting the db folder near the .jar file but it doesn't working. I don't get the values from my database.